# Operations using JTS with CRS as WGS84 or similar geographic coordinate reference systems

Tags: coordinate-system, jts-topology-suite

I need to carry out the operations of the JTS, that is a API for processing geometry on the  2D dimensional plan. Operations as Intersection, Union, Buffer, Boundary... And the parameters of this operations would be in the same CRS, but this CRS could be WGS 84 or other similar geographic coordinate reference systems.
I could make this operations using JTS without transformations or I need use other tool to transform first to the Cartesian plane, and transform the result to the CRS of the source?